# How can I get the runtime data from WinCC7.2 to another computer in the same LAN?

Tags: wincc

I have installed WinCC in a host computer, and I want to get the data from the runtime databases to another computer which is as a web server so I can build a JSP web to monitor and change the parameter of devices below the Wincc. How can I achieve that, please give some advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the Industrial Data Bridge and solve the problem.